# CachingConnectionFactory to be able to reconnect to MQ server

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Has anyone dealt with a MQ/JMS issue where MQ client loses its connection to MQ server and has to reconnect? Currently, we are forced to bounce the Java application whenever the connection is lost.
The current code uses Spring's `CachingConnectionFactory` with `JmsTemplate` and I have already tried below options -

1. Explicitly set `reconnectOnException=true`. It never invokes `reconnect()` present in `SingleConnectionFactory`. [CCF is subclass of SCF]
2. Implementing `ExceptionListener` - It never gets invoked.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: @Nikhil, Please share your exception stack trace and I recommend to use ApplicationEventPublisher interface of Spring which will check for Heartbeat signal while establishing any connections. Also, it is always recommended to establish a heartbeat signals while making any connections with other interfaces.

Comment: Hello Praveen, below is the exception trace  

org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009